# Ruby-How to build a multivalued hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

Here is my code snippet:

```
something_1.each do |i|
    something_2.each do |j|
      Data.each do |data|
       date = data.attribute('TIME_PERIOD').text
       value = data.attribute('OBS_VALUE').text
       date_value_hash[date] = value
     end
    end
  end
```

I want to capture all the values in a single date. date is the key of my hash and it may have multiple values for a single date. How can I accomplish that here? When I am using this line:

```
date_value_hash[date] = value
```

values are getting replaced each time the loop iterates. But, I want to accumulate all the values in my date_value_hash for each dates i.e. I want to build the values dynamically.

Currently I am getting this:

```
{"1990"=>"1", "1994"=>"2", "1998"=>"0"}
```

But, I want something like this:

```
{"1990"=>"1,2,3,4,5,6", "1994"=>"1,2,3,4,5,6", "1998"=>"1,2,3,4,5,6"}
```

Anyone have any idea how can I accomplish that?

Comment: why down vote please? is this very silly to ask?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your first code snippet had way more information than was necessary. Your edit improved it a bit, it's easier to see the specific question you are asking.

Comment: I understood that and changed my code stripping out the unnecessary parts. Thanks.

Comment: Also your title could be better, along the lines of "multivalued hash" instead of "dynamically changing"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this

```
magic = Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}
magic["1990"] << "A"
magic["1990"] << "B"
magic["1994"] << "C"
magic["1998"] << "D"
magic["1994"] << "F"
```

after which `magic` is

```
{"1998"=>["D"], "1994"=>["C", "F"], "1990"=>["A", "B"]}
```

and if you need the values as comma separated string (as indicated by your sample data), you'll just access them as

```
magic['1990'].join(',')
```

which yields

```
"A,B"
```

if later you want to pass `magic` around and preventing it from automagically creating keys, just wrap it as follows

```
hash = Hash.new.update(magic)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can even initialize your hash a little easier: `magic = Hash.new []`

Comment: This won't work, this will use the SAME array for all values, and it will NOT add them to the hash. `h=Hash.new([]);h[:a]<<1;h[:b]<<2` adds both values to the same array and leaves the hash empty.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach of building multi-valued hash in Ruby:

```
h = {}
(h[:key] ||= []) << "value 1"
(h[:key] ||= []) << "value 2"
puts h
```