# How to concatenate a string value in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, string-concatenation

I am opening a file with terms associated to codes. A line in the file appears as follows:

```
Pacific Ocean; D01.330.322
```

I would like them to appear in a hash. Some terms appear more than once, and I want to put its values in one string joined by `","`. The code I have is:

```
descriptor_code_hash = Hash.new
File.open('mtrees2014.bin').each do |file_line|
  file_line = file_line.chomp
  mesh_descriptor, tree_code = file_line.split(/\;/)
  descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] = tree_code
  if descriptor_code_hash.has_key? mesh_descriptor
    tree_code << "," << tree_code 
  else 
    descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] 
  end
end
```

When a term has multiple codes, the same code is concatenated once and the other unique codes for that term are not identified. Also, I don't know how to write the script to get all the codes, for example, some of the terms have six codes.

Comment: Any reason you want them codes to be coma separated string instead of array of codes?

Comment: I have to use each code from certain terms in the file to identify related codes.  I was thinking that it would be easy to split the string and get each code from there.  I have never used a hash with each value being an array of values.  If you are familiar with that strategy I would welcome your ideas!

Comment: When you state that you "have read other answers" but that "none have answered my question", it's helpful to us to know ***which answers*** that you have already tried (**link to them!**), so that we don't end up repeating the same answers, because that just wastes ***everyone's*** time, ours and yours.

Comment: Hi @Cupcake, the questions I looked at include: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687529/how-can-i-assign-multiple-values-to-a-hash-key; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567066/key-mapping-to-multiple-values; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811528/ruby-how-to-build-a-multivalued-hash.  Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: Is there any reason you are splitting by `/\;/` (or `";"`) instead of by `/;\s*/`? It looks unnatural.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not far off the mark.  Let's go through it.

**Test Data**

Here's some data for use in testing:

```
oceans = ["Pacific; 1", "Atlantic; 2", "Indian; 3",
          "Pacific; 2", "Atlantic; 1", "Pacific; 3"]
```

Rather than reading lines of a file, I have simplified things to by reading from an array of strings.  Once the code is working it's simple enough to change it to read from a file.

Now that we have some input data, we can show what we want the expected result to be, either

```
hash =
  { 'Pacific'  => ['1', '2', '3'],
    'Atlantic' => ['2', '1'],
    'Indian'   => ['1'] }
```

or

```
hash =
  { 'Pacific'  => "'1', '2', '3'",
    'Atlantic' => "'2', '1'",
    'Indian'   => "'1'" }
```

We'll use the first, as it's easiest to deal with, and if we want the second form we can easily compute it from the first:

```
hash.keys.each { |k| hash[k] = hash[k].join(',') }  
  #=> ["Pacific", "Atlantic", "Indian"]
```

But, wait, that's not a hash that's returned.  No, it's `hash.keys`.  What we want is the new value of `hash`:

```
hash #=> {"Pacific"=>"1,2,3", "Atlantic"=>"2,1", "Indian"=>"1"}
```

Aside: When posting questions to SO, it's often helpful to include some illustrative input data together with the expected result.  That tends to clarify, and save words.  Try to use as little data as possible.

**Your Code**

Here's your code, with the array `oceans` substituted for the reading of the file:

```
descriptor_code_hash = Hash.new
oceans.each do |file_line|
  file_line = file_line.chomp
  mesh_descriptor, tree_code = file_line.split(/\;/)
  descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] = tree_code

  if descriptor_code_hash.has_key? mesh_descriptor
    tree_code << "," << tree_code 
  else 
    descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] 
  end
end
```

The main problem is the line:

```
descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] = tree_code
```

Each time through the loop, the value of `descriptor_code_hash` for the key `mesh_descriptor` is reset to the value of `tree_code` for the current element of `oceans` (representing a line of the file).  You need to delete this line.

Next, we need to change your `if/else/end` statement, as follows:

```
if descriptor_code_hash.has_key? mesh_descriptor
  descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] << tree_code 
else 
  descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] = [tree_code]
end
```

This gives you the following:

```
descriptor_code_hash = Hash.new
oceans.each do |file_line|
  file_line = file_line.chomp
  mesh_descriptor, tree_code = file_line.split(/\;/)
  if descriptor_code_hash.has_key? mesh_descriptor
    descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] << tree_code 
  else 
    descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] = [tree_code]
  end
end
```

When we run this, we obtain:

```
descriptor_code_hash
  #=> {"Pacific"=>[" 1", " 2", " 3"], "Atlantic"=>[" 2", " 1"],
  #    "Indian"=>[" 3"]}
```

As you see, the result is correct, except there is a minor formatting problem.  We can fix that by changing:

```
file_line.split(/\;/)
```

to

```
file_line.split(/\;/).map { |w| w.strip }
```

which can be simplified in two ways:

```
file_line.split(';').map(&:strip)
```

Let's try it.  Suppose:

```
file_line = "Pacific; 1\n"
```

Then

```
file_line.split(';').map(&:strip) #=> ["Pacific", "1"]
```

which is the desired result.  Notice that I included a newline character at the end of the string.  That was to show you that `strip` removes it as well as whitespace.  That means you don't need the previous line:

```
file_line = file_line.chomp
```

(`file_line.chomp.split(/\s*;\s*/)` also works.)

Your code is now simplied to this:

```
descriptor_code_hash = Hash.new
oceans.each do |file_line|
  mesh_descriptor, tree_code = file_line.split(';').map(&:strip)
  if descriptor_code_hash.has_key? mesh_descriptor
    descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] << tree_code 
  else 
    descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] = [tree_code]
  end
end
```

**Polishing**

Now consider what you might do to make your code more Ruby-like.  Firstly, look at the following line used in the answer given by @BroiSatse (in lieu of your `if/else/end` construct):

```
(descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] ||= []) << tree_code
```

For any variable `a`, `a ||= []` is the same as `a = (a || [])`.  If `a` has not been defined, it will equal `nil`, so `(nil || []) => []`.  If `a` has been assigned a (non-nil) value, `(a || []) => a`.  In other words, if `descriptor_code_hash` has no key `mesh_descriptor` (meaning `descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] => nil`), `descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor]` will be assigned `[]`; otherwise, it will be assigned itself (i.e., it will not change).

After

```
descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] ||= []
```

is executed, `descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor]` will equal an array, empty or otherwise.  `<< tree_code` then appends `tree_code` to the hash value (an array).  Lastly, we could use `{}` rather than `Hash.new`, but that's purely a stylistic choice.

Your code now looks like this:

```
descriptor_code_hash = {}
oceans.each do |file_line|
  mesh_descriptor, tree_code = file_line.split(';').map(&:strip)
  (descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] ||= []) << tree_code
end
```

Let's now make this a method and make a couple more changes:

```
def descriptor_code_hash(oceans)
  oceans.each_with_object({}) do |line, hash|
    mesh_descriptor, tree_code = line.split(';').map(&:strip)
    (hash[mesh_descriptor] ||= []) << tree_code
  end
end

descriptor_code_hash(oceans)
  #=> {"Pacific"=>["1", "2", "3"], "Atlantic"=>["2", "1"], "Indian"=>["3"]}
```

I've simplified some of the variable names, because the purpose of the method is described by its name.  Read through the docs for [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) (available since version 1.9) to see how it is used.

You probably want the filename as the method argument.

One last thing: you could instead write this as follows:

```
def descriptor_code_hash(oceans)
  oceans.each_with_object(Hash.new {|k,h| h[k] = {} }) do |line, hash|
    mesh_descriptor, tree_code = line.split(';').map(&:strip)
    hash[mesh_descriptor] << tree_code
  end
end
```

Here the object is initialize to:

```
Hash.new {|k,h| h[k] = {} }
```

which makes the default value (for when a new key is added to the hash) an empty hash.  That's why the third-to-last line can be simplified as shown.

Comment: Wow Cary!  I learned more about Ruby from your answer than I have in my class for the last three months - Thank you for your extremely detailed and comprehensive answer!  I will apply your suggestions to my code.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
descriptor_code_hash = Hash.new
File.open('mtrees2014.bin').each do |file_line|
  file_line = file_line.chomp
  mesh_descriptor, tree_code = file_line.split(/\;/)
  (descriptor_code_hash[mesh_descriptor] ||= []) << tree_code
end
```

This way `descriptor_code_has[key]` is an array with all the codes from the file with given key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BroiSatse!  I ran this code and got errors until I removed "=".  The script produced a list of key/value pairs, but the values were not in an array - unless I am not looking at it properly.  I used: puts " The descriptor: #{mesh_descriptor}  and its code: #{tree_code}".  This resulted in a complete list from the hash but no codes grouped together in a string or array.  Any further thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: @user3385593 - What kind of error did you get? I can't see any `=` being safe to remove from the code above.

Comment: Hi @BroiSatse!, the error I got was "unexpected =".  When I removed the "=" from the string the script ran OK but did not return concatenated codes.